# Query json by value with Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a Postgres table where one column ("char_values") is of type "jsonb". The contents of this column does not have a fixed format for json keys, they can be anything.
[Example of the populated database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04ePY.png)

I can query with success in Postgres, for instance:

`SELECT * FROM rm_character WHERE char_values ->> 'Value3' = 'Twenty Three' AND char_values ->> 'Value6' = 'Twenty Six';`

My Java entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rm_character")
public class RMCharacter {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_person_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_person_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Date creationDate = new Date();

    @Type(JsonType.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, String> charValues = new HashMap<>();

    .... Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Since the json does not have a fixed structure, native queries are not a good option. I would like to use the Spring Data Jpa criteria, with a list of predicates, but I can't create the predicates to work with json data:

```
@Override
public List<RMCharacter> getByCriteria() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RMCharacter> cq = cb.createQuery(RMCharacter.class);
    Root<RMCharacter> person = cq.from(RMCharacter.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList();

    // Add predicate to 'Value3' = 'Twenty Three'
        // MY PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE!!
    predicates.add(cb.equal(.cb..cb.));
    
    // Add predicate to 'Value6' = 'Twenty Six'
    predicates.add(cb.equal(.cb..cb.));

    TypedQuery<RMCharacter> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    List<RMCharacter> result = query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

In this case, I don't know how to create the two predicates for querying 'Value3' and 'Value6'.